# Is it possible to load several data asynchronously with Retrofit and wait for all data before doing something else?

Tags: android, retrofit2

Here is my current code. The problem with this code is I need to wait get the data sequentially. The loading time is poor because of this. I want to use something like `.enqueue()` to get asynchronously several data at once, but I want to wait until I get all the data before continuing the process. Is it possible to do it with Retrofit?

```
List<Data> datas = new ArrayList<>();
for (long dataId : mDataIds) {
    Response<T> response = resource.getData(dataId).execute();
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        datas.add(data.body());
    }
}
//do something else
```

Comment: Is it multiple network calls and its data?

Comment: yes, it's multiple calls and I want to get all data before continuing to the next step. I can do it with `.execute()`, but it will load the data one by one which is slow. With `.enqueue()`, I can do several multiple calls at once, but I can't wait for all data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem very elegantly using RxJava.

If you never heard of [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) before, it is a solution to many of your problems.

If you don't use java8 or [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) I recommend you to start using it, as it makes working with RxJava a piece of cake.

Anyway here's what you need to do:

```
// 1. Stream each value from mDataIds
Observable.from(mDataIds)
                // 2. Create a network request for each of the data ids
                .flatMap(dataId -> resource.getData(dataId))
                // 3. Collect responses to list
                .toList()
                // Your data is ready
                .subscribe(datas -> {}, throwable -> {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Define interface with callback Model type.

```
public interface LoginService {
    @GET("/login")
    Call<List<Login>> getLogin();
}
```

In you calling method override the callback method.

```
LoginService loginService = ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class);
Call<List<Login>> call = loginService.getLogin();  
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Login>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Login>> call, Response<List<Login>> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // Login successful
        } else {
            // error response, no access to resource?
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Login>> call, Throwable t) {
        // something went completely south (like no internet connection)
        Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) First add RxJava2 dependencies to your project

2) Define retrofit api interface methods which return RxJava observable types

```
public interface DataApi {
    @GET("dataById/")
    Observable<Data> getData(@Query("id") String id);
}
```

3) Call api passing input data like below.

```
Observable.fromIterable(idList).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
       .flatMap(id -> {
              return retrofitService.getData(id).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()); 
       }).toList().
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe( listOfData -> {// do further processing }, error -> { //print errors} );
```

For reference : http://www.zoftino.com/retrofit-rxjava-android-example

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using RxJava and try it. You have something called FlatMap to combine the results.

To Start here is the tutorial start for [RxJava2 and Retrofit2](https://medium.com/3xplore/handling-api-calls-using-retrofit-2-and-rxjava-2-1871c891b6ae).